# Polymer Starter Kit 1.2.2 breaking on load because of regex replace

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

it was working fine then after I switched back to gulp serve from apache I got an undefined error in page.js in a regex replace

```
if (window.location.port ==='') {
    page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\$/, ''));
}
```

because app.baseUrl is ''.  the code is unedited but the baseurl doesn't have a "/" in it for some reason now.  the error occurse as soon a i run gulp serve.  webcomponentsready fires and is caught in routing.html.  it breaks when this calls page.js here:

```
page(app.baseUrl, function() {
  app.route = 'home';
});
```

first of all, shouldn't it not break if there isn't a slash in the url?  second, what determines the baseurl when you use gulp serve?

more routing.html

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {

// We use Page.js for routing. This is a Micro
// client-side router inspired by the Express router
// More info: https://visionmedia.github.io/page.js/

// Removes end / from app.baseUrl which page.base requires for production
if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
  page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\/$/, ''));
}

// Middleware
function scrollToTop(ctx, next) {
  app.scrollPageToTop();
  next();
}
 function closeDrawer(ctx, next) {
  app.closeDrawer();
  next();
}

// Routes
page('*', scrollToTop, closeDrawer, function(ctx, next) {
  next();
});

page('/', function() {
  app.route = 'home';
});

page(app.baseUrl, function() {
  app.route = 'home';
});

page('/users', function() {
  app.route = 'users';
});

page('/users/:name', function(data) {
  app.route = 'user-info';
  app.params = data.params;
});

page('/contact', function() {
  app.route = 'contact';
});

// 404
page('*', function() {
  app.$.toast.text = 'Can\'t find: ' + window.location.href  + '. Redirected you to Home Page';
  app.$.toast.show();
  page.redirect(app.baseUrl);
});

// add #! before urls
page({
  hashbang: true
});
```

});

Comment: Can you provide more code samples of your file `routing.html`

Comment: sure.  its in polymer starter kit 1.2.2.  I haven't edited it.

Comment: so `gulp serve` is returning an error, which task in gulp serve is responsible for it

Comment: no.  gulp serve isn't returning an error.  that is just some context.  it was working when I used apache.  then it broke when I used gulp.  it broke on    
    page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\$/, ''));

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet is used in production mode, and comment it, wont affect your code unless you are hosting you rapp

```js
// Removes end / from app.baseUrl which page.base requires for production
if (window.location.port === '') {  // if production
  page.base(app.baseUrl.replace(/\/$/, ''));
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that.  I figured I could do that but I don't want to forget about it and have my code break in production.  also I want to figure out how I broke it in the first place.  I may end up doing this though.

Answer (score 0):

Update to latest version. PSK 1.3.0 Works fine. I was having the same problem until I updated.